# How to split an array as argument values in matlab?

Tags: matlab, function

In my matlab script, I have a function handler

```
F=@(x1,x2)6+2*x1^1+3*x2^2;
```

This gives me an anonymous function as `F` that takes 2 arguments and returns the value. I also have an array of values

```
x = [1 2];
```

With the above, how can I do

```
F(x)
```

In other words, something like `F(1, 2)` but I want to use `x`, I don't want to hard code values, and it also needs to work for any dimension size, I don't want to hard code it for 2-dimension like in the above example. Basically what I'm looking for is a way to turn an array into arguments.

Can this be done in matlab?

Thanks

Comment: +1 for the great, concise wording: "turn an array into arguments"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn an array into its arguments: first turn the array into a cell array (with `num2cell`), and then turn the cell array into a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) (with `{:}`):

```
xcell = num2cell(x);
F(xcell{:})
```

Comment: I have another issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22234949/getting-index-exceeds-matrix-dimensions-error-in-matlab

Comment: @omega It's a clever answer. Don't forget to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
F=@(x)6+2*x(1)^1+3*x(2)^2;
xx = [1 2];
F(xx)
ans =

    20
```