# Getting index exceeds matrix dimensions error in matlab

Tags: matlab, function

I have this script:

```
function [ G ] = evalF( F,x,n )

    G=zeros(n,1);
    xcell = num2cell(x);

    for i=1:n
        f = F(i)
        a = f(xcell{:})
    end

end
```

and these two variables defined:

```
F = 

    @(x1,x2)6+2*x1^1+3*x2^2    @(x1,x2)3+3*x1^1+2*x2^2

x =

     1     2
```

and when I run it like this:

```
evalF(F,x,2)
```

but I get the error:

```
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in evalF (line 8)
        a = f(x{:})
```

I don't see what's wrong...
Can anyone help?

I turn an array into arguments, more info about that is here
[How to split an array as argument values in matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22234330/how-to-split-an-array-as-argument-values-in-matlab?noredirect=1#comment33763543_22234330)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because it is trying to index `f` instead of run the function stored in `f`. Why? `f` is a cell containing a function handle rather than a function handle.

To make `f` a function handle:

```
f = F{i};
```